# Connected spaces: is there a mistake in the example below from James Munkres' Topology?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

A subspace $Y$ of $X$ is seperable if it can be written as the union of nonempty, disjoint, open sets in $Y$, neither containing the limit point of the other. $Y$ should then not be connected, yet the author writes that $Y$ is connected. Why does it not matter that they do have a limit point in common?

Comment: That common limit point is not in either of the sets. Where does he write that the sets are connected? I don't think they are.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was skipping over the word  'contains'. And, no it doesn't say that the subspace is connected. Lots of confusion in my head, is all. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mark, looks like I skipped part of your question too, Ha!

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $A = [-1, 0)$ and $B = (0,1]$, then $\bar{A} = [-1,0]$ and $\bar{B} = [0, 1]$.

Thus the sets $$\bar{A} \cap B = \emptyset$$ $$\bar{B} \cap A = \emptyset.$$ So the sets $A$ and $ B$ do form a separation.

As Paul Hurst remarked in the comments, the author did not state $Y$ was connected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.